# Display product if the dates are not filled out

Tags: php, magento

I have 'active to' and 'active from' date picker. I am able to display the product info when dates are set.

```
$giftActiveFrom = $_prod->getData('product_gift_active_from');
$giftActiveTo = $_prod->getData('product_gift_active_to');
$timestamp1 = strtotime($giftActiveFrom);
$timeNow = time();
$timestamp2 = strtotime($giftActiveTo);
if(!($timeNow > $timestamp1 && $timeNow < $timestamp2)){
    return parent::productAttribute($product, $attributeHtml, $attributeName);
}
```

How to display product even when dates are not set. that is if active to and active from is not selected also I need to display the product info. 
Help!!!

Comment: What is `$_prod->getData('product_gift_active_to');` returning if the date is not set?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default time-stamp if the product date/time is not set/empty:

```
$timestamp2 = (!empty(strtotime($giftActiveTo))) ? strtotime($giftActiveTo) : strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Comment: If you find my answer useful and if it helped to solve your problem, please mark it here as such, so other users can benefit from this information.